# Cannot filter null even has implemented in where function

Tags: sql, sqlite, syntax-error

Three tables:-Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate ) Movie ( mID, title, year, director )Reviewer ( rID, name )

Find the difference between the average rating of movies released before 1980 and the average rating of movies released after 1980.

(Make sure to calculate the average rating for each movie, then the average of those averages for movies before 1980 and movies after. Don't just calculate the overall average rating before and after 1980.)

But there is always null,even I filtered the null in where function

```
''''
select r.mID,sum(stars),
count(case when year>1980 and stars is not null then stars end )as "numaf",
count(case when year<1980 and stars is not null then stars end )as "numbf",
sum(case when year>1980 and stars is not null then stars end )as "sumaf",
sum(case when year<1980 and stars is not null then stars end )as "sumbf",
(("sumaf"/"numaf")-("sumbf"/"numbf")) as "difof"
from Rating r left join movie m on r.mID = m.mID 
where stars is not null
group by r.mID
''''

and this is output, always has "NULL":
101 9   0   3   <NULL>  9   <NULL>
103 5   0   2   <NULL>  5   <NULL>
104 5   2   0   5   <NULL>  <NULL>
106 9   0   2   <NULL>  9   <NULL>
107 8   2   0   8   <NULL>  <NULL>
108 10  3   0   10  <NULL>  <NULL>
```

Comment: Problem has been solved by combine everyone's (below) advice, Thanks a lot!                                                                                                                      `select max(p.avgV)-min(P.avgV)
from(select avg(o.avgS) as avgV,
case when year > 1980 then 1 else 0 end as yearIndicator
from (select mID,avg(stars)as avgS from rating group by mID) as o
join movie m on o.mID = m.mID 
group by yearIndicator) as P `

Comment: The thing why there is so many null is because for some movie, they don't show up after year 1980,so the sum has to be null even I have filtered null values when join two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The average rating for movies is:

```
select r.mID, avg(stars) as avg_stars
from Rating r 
group by r.mID;
```

Then, to answer the question, you can join this to movies and use conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when year < 1980 then avg_stars) as avg_stars_pre1980,
       avg(case when year > 1980 then avg_stars) as avg_stars_post1980,
       (avg(case when year < 1980 then avg_stars) -
        avg(case when year > 1980 then avg_stars) a
       ) as diff       
from (select r.mID, avg(stars) as avg_stars
      from Rating r 
      group by r.mID
     ) r join
     movie m
     on r.mID = m.mID 
group by r.mID;
```

The reason you are getting `NULL` is because you *think* you are dividing column aliases defined in the `SELECT`.  However, you are really dividing strings.  So:

```
(("sumaf"/"numaf")-("sumbf"/"numbf")) as "difof"
```

is merely:

```
(('sumaf'/'numaf')-('sumbf'/'numbf')) as difof
```

Strings are interpreted as numbers, in a numeric constant, with the leading digits converted to a number.  These have no leading digits, so the values are all `0` -- resulting in a divide-by-zero.  MySQL returns `NULL` for divide by zero rather than generating an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I am still confused why i got so many nulls here even though I have filtered it in where and case.

Comment: @Olly . . . If there are no movies during a time period, then the `sum()` returns `NULL`.  I explained the issue with the last column in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I know why, maybe for some movie id, there is no after 1980., so sum still show null.

Answer (score 1):

To get the Avg rating of movies split out by before and after 1980, you can do something like:

```
SELECT SUM(avgRating)/Count(mID), yearSection
FROM (
    SELECT 
       r.mid,
       round(sum(stars),2)/count(r.mID) as avgRating,
       case when year > 1980 then 1 else 0 end as yearSection
from Rating r left join movie m on r.mID = m.mID 
where stars is not null
group by r.mID
     )AS foo
GROUP BY yearSection
```

This won't result in any nulls. Also you should need to round the sum as a decimal, or else your averages won't be correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This really can give out an answer for this question. but I still confused why i got null here when I filtered it.

Comment: Yes - but I wanted to show you a cleaner way of figuring this out :)

Comment: thanks a lot! I solved it in this way:                                                                                          `select max(p.avgV)-min(P.avgV) from(select avg(o.avgS) as avgV, case when year > 1980 then 1 else 0 end as yearIndicator from (select mID,avg(stars)as avgS from rating group by mID) as o join movie m on o.mID = m.mID group by yearIndicator) as P`